# using mssql_connect to connect to a DB in another server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

We are using the below script.

Actually our DB is in one server (say www.server1.com) and the PHP file

containing the below connection string is in another server (say

www.server2.com)

If we place the PHP file containing the below script in the same server

where the DB exists that is www.server1.com/dbconnection.php it is working

fine.

But if we place the PHP file containing the below script in another server

www.server2.com/dbconnection.php it is not working. This displays the

error 'Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL'  Please advise.

Also to handle error if we use 'die('MSSQL error: ' .

mssql_get_last_message());' nothing displays just an empty page.

Please advise how to handle errors.

### Script (dbconnection.php)

```
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x,xxxx'; //IP, Port

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

if (!$link) {
die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}

// Connect to DB
$db=mssql_select_db("databasename",$link) or die("Unable to select 

database ");
```

Thank You

Comment: Try to conect to the server one from the server two using some management studio like SSMS, Database.NET or any other thing that allows connection to DB. Most likely you have problems with connection string and/or server1 configuration which disallows the outer connection. Or may be firewall is blocking the port for external connection.

Answer (score 0):

How to get error message, I do not know, but if you are migrating your PHP app from windows server to linux (FTP servers are more usual on linux), you can try change:

```
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x,xxxx'; //IP, Port
```

to

```
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx'; //IP: Port
```

As described in first parameter of manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php